# Regex uppercase and numbers

Tags: regex, uppercase

Hi everyone i need a Regex the first letter needs to be 'L' uppercase and the rest only numbers the size needs to be 9.

Actually I'm using this:

```
Regex RgxUrl = new Regex("[^a-z0-9]");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be

```
^L[0-9]{8}$
```

`^` marks the beginning of string/line and `$` marks the end of string/line

`{8}` is a qauntifier which would match 8 digits.

Comment: i @Anirudh I use the answer but if a put "La1234567" marks right only the first letter could be letter and needs to be 'L', any ideas, thanks

Comment: @JVazquez you said that the first letter should be `L` and the rest should be digits..please make your question clear..do you want alphabets at the beginning..If yes then how many..Can the input contain alphabets as well as digits?

Comment: I need specifically the letter L only 1 letter and needs to be 'L' and the other eight digits needs to be numbers for example. 

L01234567

Comment: @JVazquez THAT'S what the above regex does

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I had another error in my code. Te Regex work's fine